# Can portions of my PhD thesis be later submitted to conferences?

Tags: phd, conference

It's fairly standard to submit thesis chapters to journals. However, in my field (theoretical computer science) conference publication is much more important. Is there any problem with taking a section of my thesis and submitting it later to a conference? Would the conference object that this was dual submission?

Comment: Conferences : computer science :: journals : every other STEM field

Comment: Not that there is anything wrong with the answer here or JeffE's comment, but is there a reason you didn't start by asking your advisor or at least someone in your department?

Comment: @ Kimball, I spoke to my advisor who did not know the answer, and suggested I ask around. I cannot ask my department because this is a matter of conference policy not departmental policy, but of the conference policy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In computer science in general, you can submit thesis extracts to conference just as freely as you would submit them to a journal.  In both cases, the principle is the same: a thesis is not really a peer-reviewed publication, so your submission would still be the first peer-reviewed publication of the material.  You must, however, cite your thesis and clearly acknowledge the source of the material as being adapted from your thesis.

Comment: +1. Could you clarify the meaning of "extracts" in this context or point to related existing question? Would it be interesting for the community, if I would submit a more general question on strategies (approaches) of converting dissertation into one or more research papers?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I think that such a question would be good, if you can figure out how to narrow it down enough to not be immediately closed as "too broad"

Comment: Well, that was the point of my comment. Such question, being general, would by definition be _relatively_ broad. However, it would be _answerable_, as I'd request people to briefly _outline_ strategies (approaches) along several suggested dimensions.